# 定期決済にて発生するトランザクションの個別TRANSACTIONID

Tags: paypal

定期決済で自動的に発生するトランザクションには、それぞれ個別にTRANSACTIONIDが付与されるでしょうか。
またそのTRANSACTIONIDでrefundできるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

定期決済にて自動的に発生するトランザクションには、それぞれ個別のTRANASCTIONIDが付与されます（IPNで通知されます）。
おっしゃるようにTRANSACTIONIDでrefundも可能です。